# Passing parms to Controller from View with Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two simple questions that I am hoping someone could answer... It's been asked several times on the web, but I cannot find a post that clearly state what I need below...

question 1:
How do you get the values from the View to pass to the Controller where the values already exist on the View? In other words, I need the @loanID value. This value is a textbox on the form and is not part of the model.

```
<label for="txtLoanID">Loan ID :</label>
                            @(Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBox()
                                        .Name("txtLoanID")
                                        .Placeholder("Enter LoanID")
                                )

@using (Html.BeginForm("GeneratePDF", "Home", new { @loanID = loanID }, FormMethod.Post))
```

question 2:
How can I pass multiple values using the above line to the Controller, specifically, a dropdownlist text value which is also not part of the model.

Answer (score 1):

The textbox should be in the form so it gets posted back by it.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GeneratePDF", "Home", FormMethod.Post))    {
    <label for="txtLoanID">Loan ID :</label>                             
     @Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBox().Name("txtLoanID").Placeholder("Enter LoanID")                               
}
```

then your controller should be able to get it through model binding

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(int txtLoadID)
{
}
```

Comment: My model only consists of two collections of Checkboxes. The textbox is not part of the model. So, I can move the textbox within the form, but for now, I think I can check it with the FormCollection object.